# Firebase Phone Authentication in PHP instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can successfully send verification code using firebase with the code below in Javascript :

```
firebase.auth()
            .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
            .then(function(confirmationResult) {
              log('SMS sent');
              window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
 
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              log('Error : SMS not sent '+error);
   
            });
```

My issue is that malicious users can execute the script above as many times they want abusing the authentication system, I would like to control the requests in the backend (PHP) is it possible?

Comment: Save the verification code in the DB and set expiry for it to be requested again OR You could also save the user `$_SESSION` in php to avoid multiple requests coming from the same IP address.

Comment: The request is done by Firebase , please read my question one more time to understand.

Comment: Have you actually tried to misuse it? What happens if you repeatedly call this function in your code? Do you get multiple sms messages?

Comment: P.s. it's "authentication". "authentification" is not a word. :-)

Comment: I don’t work with Firebase daily, but it would surprise me if they did not implement any rate limiting on this type of service by default; as @ADyson suggested, have you actually replicated any scenario in a production environment showing that this *can* be abused in this way?

Comment: @ADyson Actually it's a french word  :-) , I didn't test calling the function more one time, but Firebase let sending many verification codes per user par few minutes and I would like to limit that ability to only 1 or 2 requests per user per day.

Comment: @CoDevloop You could swap out the Firebase JavaScript calls here for a call to the PHP script on your server that provides the same functionality but implements the rate limiting at your desired settings; however, keep in mind that “*1 or 2 requests per user per day*” is likely to cause some friction amongst users who are in the habit of logging out and in to services more than this amount of times in a single day. Consider applying a bit more logic than that to determine whether to rate limit a specific request (i.e., the success/failure of the previous authentication).

Comment: `Firebase let sending many verification codes per user par few minutes `...ok and why is that a problem for you? If they don't mind then what issue does it cause? It uses firebase resources to do that, not yours. If they didn't want that they would put a limit on it.

Comment: *firebaser here* ADyson summarizes it well: Firebase Authentication very intentionally only charges you for completed authentication cycles, not for the number of SMS/text messages that are sent/requested.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What if Firebase team change the logic and charge for every sent SMS ? this way we have to put extra efforts and time to implement a rate limit system.

Comment: If such a change were to be made, it would be communicated well ahead of time. That would then also be a good time to implement your own rate limiting. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯